# Unexpected wilting and leaves curling in a serrano pepper plant

Tags: diseases, peppers

About 5 days ago, I noticed that one of my 5 serrano pepper plants that a planted in a 10l container started to wilt a bit with some leaves that started to curl. After searching on the internet, I realised it could be some underwatering problem, so I reasonably watered it (even though my 4 other serrano plants which are in the same container were doing completely fine, so I wasn't  completely convinced that underwatering was the cause anyway), but obviously it gave no results, and the affected plant continued to wilt and curl even more. I was intrigued by that, and I started to dig around the bottom part of the stem in the soil until I observed a sudden narrowing down of the stem at the base. After checking in the 4 other serrano's, there wasn't any narrowing down, so I suspect this narrowing down of the stem to be linked with the wilting and curling of the plant, but I have no clues about what's happening  and how to save my plant. So what do you think is happening to my plant and what do you think I could do to save it? Thanks for your answers ;)[image: stem narrowing down]

Comment: I forgot to mention it and I don't konw if it is useful anyway but I noticed that the affected plant's stem is very hard to the touch and it's leaves are normal to the touch ( doesn't feel like dehydrated at all), it's just that they are curling and wilting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a case of damping-off. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damping_off

Unfortunately, this pepper is a loss.